# C# Windows Form - AutoScroll while designing

Tags: c#, .net, forms, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to have a windows form be scrollable while I edit it. What I mean by this is I have 4 fields of text boxes that reappear 20 times, and I can not fit them all on the form, even when I have extended the form size to the max. Once it stops letting me extend, the form just pastes the text fields on top of one another.

[You can See I have maxed out the form size and still need these rows to appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjxXR.png)

As an additional note:

This is the bottom panel of a SplitContainer, which has Autoscroll enabled, so I am only able to scroll when I size the form smaller than the existing list.

Is there any way, while I am still the designing the form that I can invoke the scroll bar to have more of these text fields? (Style isn't great,but I am bound to 4 text fields, twenty times.

tldr: I need to have more of these 4 text fields but I cannot edit the bottom of the form without them overlapping.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: Let me know if this isn't a duplicate (see both my answers) and I'll reopen.

Comment: Make the controls 'by hand', maybe even at runtime, skip the entire designer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try a FlowLayoutPanel inside your SplitContainer, then enable "Autoscroll" on the flowPanel
and you can now scroll down and edit all your textfields